# Why cannot update status?

Tags: php

I am tying to update table status after success run the if condition and my condition is work well. I try to echo something inside if condition and its work. But update sql cannot function after I run through all the code. I have no idea where goes wrong of my code. I had try several time to echo different value inside if condition and there is no problem to print out all the things.

This is php code:

```
<?
require_once "lib/base.inc.php";

$arrResult = $oAdminEmail->getQueEmail();

for($i=0; $i<count($arrResult); $i++)
{
    $email = $arrResult[$i]['contact_email'];
    $name = $arrResult[$i]['contact_first']." ".$arrResult[$i]['contact_last'];
    $message = $arrResult[$i]['message']; 
    $subject = $arrResult[$i]['subject'];
    $sendMail = $eMailer->sendEDM($email,$name,$subject,$message);
    $iId = $arrResult[$i]['id'];
    if ($sendMail) 
            {
                $update['status'] = 1;
                $update_edm = $oAdminEmail->updateEmailStatus($update,$iId);
            }
} 


?>
```

This is sql statement :

```
function updateEmailStatus($record, $iId)
        {
            global $db;

            $bResult = false;

            if(empty($iId)) return $bResult;

            $record['send_timestamp'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
            $sUpdRecordList = $db->cpsFldUpdtSQLSeg($record); 

            $stmt = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EMAIL_OUTGOING." SET ".$sUpdRecordList." WHERE id =".$iId;

            if(!$db->Execute($stmt)) return $bResult;

            return true;

        }
```

Comment: your id is int or string?

Comment: what mean by id is int or string?

Comment: I mean data type of your "Id" which the value pass to sql statement.

Comment: ops. It's string. any problem on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your sql statement. If you pass string value to sql and it must be put '' to cover your string value.

This is your sql statement :

```
$stmt = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EMAIL_OUTGOING." SET ".$sUpdRecordList." WHERE id =".$iId;
```

Copy this code and replace to your sql :

```
$stmt = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EMAIL_OUTGOING." SET ".$sUpdRecordList." WHERE id ='".$iId."'";
```